# I am trying to create a seven segment scoreboard

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a seven segment display to hold the score of my rock paper scissors game. But when I move the rectangles on one side over it will either move the other clock or revert the first clock on the left side back over to the left. Right now both clocks are on the far sides of the screen, I preferably want them in the middle. This is my first time using JavaFX, I've been learning as I have been making the game. Also, if theres any way I can condense some of the code I am open to suggestion. Thank you!

**Main class:**

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Label label1 = new Label();
    Scene scene1, scene2;

    //ScoreBoard Rectangles
    Group root = new Group();

    public static Shapes shape = new Shapes();
    public static Rectangle r, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6;
    public static final int ROCK = 0;
    public static final int PAPER = 1;
    public static final int SCISSORS = 2;
    public static int userChoice;
    public static int compChoice;
    public static int userCounter = 0;
    public static int compCounter = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setResizable(false);

        //Layouts
        VBox layout = new VBox(20);
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);

        //Background color
        BackgroundFill backFill = new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK,       CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY);
        Background background = new Background(backFill);
        layout.setBackground(background);

        //Start Screen Label
        Label label = new Label("Rock Paper Scissors");
        label.setFont(Font.font(20));
        label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);

        //Start Button
        Button myButton = new Button("Start");
        myButton.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene2));

        //Exit Button
        Button exit = new Button("Exit");
        exit.setOnAction(e -> System.exit(0));

        //Add Children
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(myButton, exit);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label, hbox);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //Add to scene1
        scene1 = new Scene(layout, 300, 300, Color.BLACK);

        //Layout 2
        VBox layout1 = new VBox(10);
        label1.setText(" ");
        label1.setFont(Font.font(18)); //Setting font size
        label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        layout1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
        HBox layout2 = new HBox(10);
        HBox lay2 = new HBox(10);

        //ScoreBoard Created
        root = shape.displayRect();

        //Rock Button
        Button rock = new Button("Rock");
        rock.setOnAction(e -> {
            userChoice = ROCK;
            compChoice = compChoice();
            label1 = winner(label1);
            shape.clearRect(root);
            shape.fillRect(root, userCounter, compCounter);
        });

        //Paper Button
        Button paper = new Button("Paper");
        paper.setOnAction(e -> {
            userChoice = PAPER;
            compChoice = compChoice();
            label1 = winner(label1);
            shape.clearRect(root);
            shape.fillRect(root, userCounter, compCounter);
        });

        //Scissor Button
        Button scissors = new Button("Scissors");
        scissors.setOnAction(e -> {
            userChoice = SCISSORS;
            compChoice = compChoice();
            label1 = winner(label1);
            shape.clearRect(root);
            shape.fillRect(root, userCounter, compCounter);
        });

        //Quit Button
        Button quit = new Button("Return");
        quit.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene1));

        //Add Children
        lay2.getChildren().add(label1);
        lay2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout2.getChildren().addAll(rock, paper, scissors, quit);
        layout2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(root, lay2, layout2);
        vbox.setBackground(background);

        //Add to scene2
        scene2 = new Scene(vbox, 300, 300);

        window.setTitle("Rock Paper Scissors");
        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.show();
    }

    public static int compChoice() {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randNum = rand.nextInt(3);

        return randNum;
    }

    public static Label winner(Label label1) {    
        label1.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        label1.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

        if (userChoice == ROCK && compChoice == SCISSORS) {
            label1.setText("You WIN\nRock beats Scissors");
            userCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == ROCK && compChoice == PAPER) {
            label1.setText("You LOSE\nPaper beats Rock");
            compCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == PAPER && compChoice == ROCK) {
            label1.setText("You WIN\nPaper beats Rock");
            userCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == PAPER && compChoice == SCISSORS) {
            label1.setText("You LOSE\nScissors beats Paper");
            compCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == SCISSORS && compChoice == ROCK) {
            label1.setText("You LOSE\nRock beats Scissors");
            compCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == SCISSORS && compChoice == PAPER) {
            label1.setText("You WIN\nScissors beats Paper");
            userCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == compChoice)
            label1.setText("TIE\n    ");

        return label1;
    }    
}
```

**Shapes class:**

```java
package sample;

import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class Shapes {    
    Rectangle r,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6;
    Rectangle rc,rc1,rc2,rc3,rc4,rc5,rc6;

    public Group displayRect() {    
        //User ScoreBoard
        r = new Rectangle(10,10,10,40); //10 , 50
        r.setArcWidth(20);
        r.setArcHeight(20);

        r1 = new Rectangle(20,0,40,10); //20 , 40
        r1.setArcWidth(20);
        r1.setArcHeight(20);

        r2 = new Rectangle(60,10,10,40); //60 , 50
        r2.setArcWidth(20);
        r2.setArcHeight(20);

        r3 = new Rectangle(20,50,40,10); //20 , 90
        r3.setArcWidth(20);
        r3.setArcHeight(20);

        r4 = new Rectangle(10,60,10,40); // 10 , 100
        r4.setArcWidth(20);
        r4.setArcHeight(20);

        r5 = new Rectangle(60,60,10,40); //60 , 100
        r5.setArcWidth(20);
        r5.setArcHeight(20);

        r6 = new Rectangle(20,100,40,10); //20 , 140
        r6.setArcWidth(20);
        r6.setArcHeight(20);

        //Computer ScoreBoard
        rc = new Rectangle(250, 10, 10,40);
        rc.setArcWidth(20);
        rc.setArcHeight(20);

        rc1 = new Rectangle(260,0,40,10);
        rc1.setArcWidth(20);
        rc1.setArcHeight(20);

        rc2 = new Rectangle(300,10,10,40);
        rc2.setArcWidth(20);
        rc2.setArcHeight(20);

        rc3 = new Rectangle(260,50,40,10);
        rc3.setArcWidth(20);
        rc3.setArcHeight(20);

        rc4 = new Rectangle(250,60,10,40);
        rc4.setArcWidth(20);
        rc4.setArcHeight(20);

        rc5 = new Rectangle(300,60,10,40);
        rc5.setArcWidth(20);
        rc5.setArcHeight(20);

        rc6 = new Rectangle(260,100,40,10);
        rc6.setArcWidth(20);
        rc6.setArcHeight(20);

        Group root = new Group(r,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,rc,rc1,rc2,rc3,rc4,rc5,rc6);

        return root;
    }

    public void clearRect(Group root) {    
        r.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        r1.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        r2.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        r3.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        r4.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        r5.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        r6.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        rc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        rc1.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        rc2.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        rc3.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        rc4.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        rc5.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        rc6.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void fillRect(Group root, int userCounter, int compCounter) {    
        if (userCounter == 1) {
            r2.setFill(Color.RED);
            r5.setFill(Color.RED);
        }

        if (userCounter == 2) {
            r1.setFill(Color.RED);
            r2.setFill(Color.RED);
            r3.setFill(Color.RED);
            r4.setFill(Color.RED);
            r6.setFill(Color.RED);
        }

        if (userCounter == 3) {
            r1.setFill(Color.RED);
            r2.setFill(Color.RED);
            r3.setFill(Color.RED);
            r5.setFill(Color.RED);
            r6.setFill(Color.RED);
        }

        if (userCounter == 4) {
            r.setFill(Color.RED);
            r2.setFill(Color.RED);
            r3.setFill(Color.RED);
            r5.setFill(Color.RED);
        }

        if (userCounter == 5) {
            r.setFill(Color.RED);
            r1.setFill(Color.RED);
            r3.setFill(Color.RED);
            r5.setFill(Color.RED);
            r6.setFill(Color.RED);
        }

        if (userCounter == 6) {
            r.setFill(Color.RED);
            r1.setFill(Color.RED);
            r3.setFill(Color.RED);
            r4.setFill(Color.RED);
            r5.setFill(Color.RED);
            r6.setFill(Color.RED);
        }

        if (userCounter == 7) {
            r1.setFill(Color.RED);
            r2.setFill(Color.RED);
            r5.setFill(Color.RED);
        }

        if (userCounter == 8) {
            r.setFill(Color.RED);
            r1.setFill(Color.RED);
            r2.setFill(Color.RED);
            r3.setFill(Color.RED);
            r4.setFill(Color.RED);
            r5.setFill(Color.RED);
            r6.setFill(Color.RED);
        }

        if (userCounter == 9) {
            r.setFill(Color.RED);
            r1.setFill(Color.RED);
            r2.setFill(Color.RED);
            r3.setFill(Color.RED);
            r5.setFill(Color.RED);
            r6.setFill(Color.RED);
        }

        switch (compCounter) {
            case 1:
                rc2.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc5.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 2:
                rc1.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc2.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc3.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc4.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 3:
                rc1.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc2.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc3.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc5.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 4:
                rc.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc2.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc3.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc5.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 5:
                rc.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc1.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc3.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc5.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 6:
                rc.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc1.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc3.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc4.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc5.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 7:
                rc1.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc2.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc5.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 8:
                rc.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc1.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc2.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc3.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc4.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc5.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 9:
                rc.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc1.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc2.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc3.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc5.setFill(Color.RED);
                rc6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            default: break;
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you simply just want your scoreboards to be centered instead of near the sides. I've fixed that, but after looking through your code I ended up adding tweaks so you won't "trip on your own feet" later on (keep in mind these are quick fixes, there's still more I would change). The most obvious problems I saw were repetitive code and instantiating/returning variables that simply aren't used so I fixed most of that. I would make sure all your variables are named in meaningful ways so it's easier to understand (i.e. label, label1 need something more descriptive).
Main:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import java.util.Random;

public class test extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Label label1 = new Label();
    Scene scene1, scene2;

    //ScoreBoard Rectangles
    Group userScoreRoot, computerScoreRoot;

    public static ScoreBoard userScoreBoard = new ScoreBoard();
    public static ScoreBoard computerScoreBoard = new ScoreBoard();
    public static final int ROCK = 0;
    public static final int PAPER = 1;
    public static final int SCISSORS = 2;
    public static int userChoice;
    public static int compChoice;
    public static int userCounter = 0;
    public static int compCounter = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setResizable(false);


        //Layouts
        VBox layout = new VBox(20);
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);

        //Background color
        BackgroundFill backFill = new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY);
        Background background = new Background(backFill);
        layout.setBackground(background);

        //Start Screen Label
        Label label = new Label("Rock Paper Scissors");
        label.setFont(Font.font(20));
        label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);

        //Start Button
        Button myButton = new Button("Start");
        myButton.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene2));

        //Exit Button
        Button exit = new Button("Exit");
        exit.setOnAction(e -> System.exit(0));

        //Add Children
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(myButton, exit);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label, hbox);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //Add to scene1
        scene1 = new Scene(layout, 300, 300, Color.BLACK);

        //Layout 2
        VBox layout1 = new VBox(10);
        label1.setText(" \n ");
        label1.setFont(Font.font(18)); //Setting font size
        label1.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        label1.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        label.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        layout1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
        HBox layout2 = new HBox(10);
        HBox lay2 = new HBox(10);


        //ScoreBoard Created
        userScoreRoot = userScoreBoard.getRoot();
        computerScoreRoot = computerScoreBoard.getRoot();

        //Rock Button
        Button rock = new Button("Rock");
        rock.setOnAction(e -> {
            userChoice = ROCK;
            compChoice = compChoice();
            winner(label1);
        });
        //Paper Button
        Button paper = new Button("Paper");
        paper.setOnAction(e -> {
            userChoice = PAPER;
            compChoice = compChoice();
            winner(label1);
        });
        //Scissor Button
        Button scissors = new Button("Scissors");
        scissors.setOnAction(e -> {
            userChoice = SCISSORS;
            compChoice = compChoice();
            winner(label1);
        });

        //Quit Button
        Button quit = new Button("Return");
        quit.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene1));

        Region region1 = new Region();
        Region region2 = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(region1, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox.setHgrow(region2, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox scoreBox = new HBox(40);
        scoreBox.getChildren().addAll(region1, userScoreRoot, computerScoreRoot, region2);

        //Add Children
        lay2.getChildren().add(label1);
        lay2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout2.getChildren().addAll(rock, paper, scissors, quit);
        layout2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(scoreBox, lay2, layout2);
        vbox.setBackground(background);

        //Add to scene2
        scene2 = new Scene(vbox, 300, 300);

        window.setTitle("Rock Paper Scissors");
        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.show();
    }

    public static int compChoice() {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randNum = rand.nextInt(3);

        return randNum;
    }

    public static void winner(Label label1) {
        /*String[] result = new String[] {"TIE\n ", "You WIN\n ", "You LOSE\n "}; 
        String[] choice = new String[] {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};
        int index = Math.abs(((userChoice - compChoice) % 3));
        String answer = result[index];
        if(index == 1) {
            userCounter++;
            answer += choice[userChoice] + " beats " + choice[compChoice];
        }
        else if(index == 2) {
            compCounter++;
            answer += choice[compChoice] + " beats " + choice[userChoice];
        }
        label1.setText(answer);*/
        if (userChoice == ROCK && compChoice == SCISSORS) {
            label1.setText("You WIN\nRock beats Scissors");
            userCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == ROCK && compChoice == PAPER) {
            label1.setText("You LOSE\nPaper beats Rock");
            compCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == PAPER && compChoice == ROCK) {
            label1.setText("You WIN\nPaper beats Rock");
            userCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == PAPER && compChoice == SCISSORS) {
            label1.setText("You LOSE\nScissors beats Paper");
            compCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == SCISSORS && compChoice == ROCK) {
            label1.setText("You LOSE\nRock beats Scissors");
            compCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == SCISSORS && compChoice == PAPER) {
            label1.setText("You WIN\nScissors beats Paper");
            userCounter++;
        }

        if (userChoice == compChoice)
            label1.setText("TIE\n    ");

        userScoreBoard.setScore(userCounter);
        computerScoreBoard.setScore(compCounter);
    }

}
```

ScoreBoard class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class ScoreBoard {

    Rectangle r,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6;
    Rectangle[] display;
    Group root;

    public ScoreBoard() {
        r = new Rectangle(10,10,10,40); //10 , 50

        r1 = new Rectangle(20,0,40,10); //20 , 40

        r2 = new Rectangle(60,10,10,40); //60 , 50

        r3 = new Rectangle(20,50,40,10); //20 , 90

        r4 = new Rectangle(10,60,10,40); // 10 , 100

        r5 = new Rectangle(60,60,10,40); //60 , 100

        r6 = new Rectangle(20,100,40,10); //20 , 140

        display = new Rectangle[]{r,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6};
        for(Rectangle rec : display) {
            rec.setArcWidth(20);
            rec.setArcHeight(20);
        }

        root = new Group(display);
    }

    public void clearRect() {
        for(Rectangle r : display) r.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        clearRect();
        switch (score%9) {
            case 0:
                 r.setFill(Color.RED);
                 r1.setFill(Color.RED);
                 r2.setFill(Color.RED);
                 r4.setFill(Color.RED);
                 r5.setFill(Color.RED);
                 r6.setFill(Color.RED);
                 break;
            case 1:
                r2.setFill(Color.RED);
                r5.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 2:
                r1.setFill(Color.RED);
                r2.setFill(Color.RED);
                r3.setFill(Color.RED);
                r4.setFill(Color.RED);
                r6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 3:
                r1.setFill(Color.RED);
                r2.setFill(Color.RED);
                r3.setFill(Color.RED);
                r5.setFill(Color.RED);
                r6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 4:
                r.setFill(Color.RED);
                r2.setFill(Color.RED);
                r3.setFill(Color.RED);
                r5.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 5:
                r.setFill(Color.RED);
                r1.setFill(Color.RED);
                r3.setFill(Color.RED);
                r5.setFill(Color.RED);
                r6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 6:
                r.setFill(Color.RED);
                r1.setFill(Color.RED);
                r3.setFill(Color.RED);
                r4.setFill(Color.RED);
                r5.setFill(Color.RED);
                r6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 7:
                r1.setFill(Color.RED);
                r2.setFill(Color.RED);
                r5.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 8:
                r.setFill(Color.RED);
                r1.setFill(Color.RED);
                r2.setFill(Color.RED);
                r3.setFill(Color.RED);
                r4.setFill(Color.RED);
                r5.setFill(Color.RED);
                r6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 9:
                r.setFill(Color.RED);
                r1.setFill(Color.RED);
                r2.setFill(Color.RED);
                r3.setFill(Color.RED);
                r5.setFill(Color.RED);
                r6.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;
            default: break;
        }

    }

    public Group getRoot() {
        return this.root;
    }
}
```

Once you get your feet more wet with JavaFX, if you don't mind transferring a lot of the GUI-related code into xml, look into fxml and SceneBuilder.

I have left an optional commented code for calculating the winner if you wanted something more clever. It replaces your IF statements but is less readable. The two arrays can be static final and can replace your Rock, Paper, and Scissors ints.